# NPM - Resolving Peer Dependencies in Package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies, package.json

I’m wondering if I am resolving unmet peer dependencies correctly in my package.json. If I encounter the error, `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY {package@version}`, should I install the dependency to “dependencies” or “devDependencies” or does it depend?

I have tried

```
npm install --save {package}
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev {package}
```

As a note, I’m running the following after each installation -

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

My specific issue is that after running `npm install`, I have the following unmet peer dependencies under the project root. Only @angular core & common are under another package -

```
path/to/app
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@4.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.1.0 invalid
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.1.0 invalid
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.3
├─┬ @swimlane/ngx-charts-dag@1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@~2.4.5
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@~2.4.5
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY d3@4.8.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY node-sass@^4.0.0
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.3.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.9
```

However, even after installing using either of the following two commands followed by removing the node_modules & cleaning the cache, I still have the unmet dependencies.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/animations @angular/common @angular/compiler @angular/core @angular/platform-browser @angular/common @angular/core d3 less rxjs zone.js

npm install --save @angular/animations @angular/common @angular/compiler @angular/core @angular/platform-browser @angular/common @angular/core d3 less rxjs zone.js
```

So most importantly, is my approach to installing the UNMET dependencies correct? And if someone knows a fix for my issue, I’d appreciate it.

EDIT:
Using npm version 4.2.0 and here are my dependencies with the right ngx-charts-dag version-

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.3",
    "d3": "4.8.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts-dag": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "zone.js": “0.8.9”,
    …
  }
```

I'm still seeing unmet peer dependency issues under the root of the project with the exact version in the package.json -

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.3
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY d3@4.8.0
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.3.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.9
```

EDIT2: 
Some fixes provided by Mitch removed the unmet peer dependencies for rxjs@5.3.0 & zone.js@0.8.9. These are caused by deprecated "ng2d3", which has moved to ngx-charts. "angular2-google-maps" also has an unmet peer dependency for zone.js@0.8.9. What's still puzzling is that I receive the following UNMET PEER DEPENDENCIES after removing "ng2d3" and "angular2-google-maps"

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.0.3
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@4.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.3
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY d3@4.2.2
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.5.0
```

These match the exact versions specified in my package.json -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.3",
    "d3": "4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "2.5.0",
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a version for npm specified in your package.json? And what version of npm are you currently running?

Comment: I don't specify my npm version in my package.json. I am using 4.2.0

Comment: Angular is a bit tricky with dependencies. Can you remove `node_modules` and update your package.json to include the *exact* versions mentioned in your warning? e.g. `"@angular/animations": "4.1.0"`

Comment: same issue unfortunately. Does my approach look correct?

Comment: `"@angular/core"` and `common` should likely not be in your `devDependencies`—that's a place for build tools, development tools, testing frameworks, etc. What package is throwing the "UNMET PEER" issue?

Comment: Most seem to be under the project root. @angular/common & @angular/core are under @swimlane/ngx-charts-dag. Those unmet dependencies are why I added those specific versions in the devDependencies. I did this because I think it is what's recommended in the angular.io guide, "It is your responsibility to list all peer dependency packages among your own devDependencies." [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html). I was surprised to learn that so if I'm misunderstanding, please let me know

Comment: Have you tried v4.0.3 instead of 4.1.0? i.e. 
animations@4.0.3
core@4.0.3

Comment: I reverted back to v4.0.3 and still am getting some puzzling UNMET dependencies for @angular/animations, @angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/compiler-cli, @angular/core, @angular/platform-browser, and @angular/platform-browser-dynamic that match the exact version specified in my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the `ngx-charts-dag` repo:

> Note: ngx-charts-dag 2.0.0 works only with Angular 4.x. To use ngx-charts-dag with Angular 2.x, use ngx-charts-dag 1.x.

You are trying to use ngx-charts-dag@1.0.0 and angular@4.x, which are not compatible. Either downgrade all Angular to 2.x, or upgrade ngx-charts-dag to 2.x.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the dag version and @angular versions helped remove those peer dependencies. I'm still receiving unmet peer dependency errors under the root even though these errors are for the exact versions I have in my package.json. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: A couple of things could be causing that: 1. A dirty `node_modules` folder, 2. Another package that is throwing those same peer dependency errors, 3.  Other incompatibilities within your `angular` modules. To be clear: Angular wants *all* of the dependencies to be the same; you cannot have `@angular/animations@2.0.1` and `@angular/core@4.0.1` **anywhere** in your package.json. They must all be set to the same version.

Comment: I edited my package.json to remove any duplicate packages in the devDependencies ("@angular/common", etc.) & rm -rf node_modules; npm cache clean. If it's possible for number 2 to still be the cause, do you know if there's another way I can tell if another package has these peer dependency errors other than looking at the output of npm install?

Comment: I'm assuming you also tried `rm -rf ~/.npm && npm cache clean`—that is the correct way to handle the error I think you're mentioning. You can check peerDeps when running `npm install`, with `npm info @swimlane/ngx-charts-dag peerDependencies` (for example), or use a package like [`install-peerdeps`](https://github.com/nathanhleung/install-peerdeps) to just try to handle it all for you.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I took a look at the peerDependencies in the package.json and don't see anything that would cause the unmet peer dependencies errors that I'm getting.

Comment: @DavidStreid Do you mean you looked at the peerDependencies of your root `package.json`? Because you need to check *each* of the peerDependencies in each module in your `node_modules` folder to really get at the problem. The easiest way honestly is to delete `node_modules` and `npm i` and pay attention to the error message. Also can you confirm you tried `rm -rf ~/.npm && npm cache clean`?

Comment: I ran `npm info {package} peerDependencies` for each package in dependencies & peerDependencies of my package.json. I changed my script to run `rm -rf ~/.npm && npm cache clean` after each package.json update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142936/discussion-between-mitch-lillie-and-david-streid).